# Are there method to get all enabled buttons from pagingtoolbar?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

My greetings !

I am trying to focus on first pagingtoolbar`s button by hot key. For example, when it will be pushed combination **CTRL + -->**, the focus will be on first enabled button of pagingtoolbar.

At this time I can get fisrt disabled button:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('pagingtoolbar button{isDisabled()}')[0]
```

**But I need a code like that:**

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('pagingtoolbar button{isEnabled()}')[0]
```

I have thought that there is such method in Ext.button.Button, but I could not find it. 
Obviously, I can resolve my problem by another way, for example, I can get all enabled buttons in paging toolbar by this code:

```
var buttons = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('pagingtoolbar button');
var en_buttons = [];
for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
  if( !buttons[i].isDisabled() )en_buttons.push(buttons[i]);
}
en_buttons[0].focus(false,100);
```

But I believe that there are no need to write such code, it must be resolved by one line of code.

With regards ,
A

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `disabled` property.

Disabled buttons:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('pagingtoolbar button[disabled=true]')
```

Enabled buttons:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('pagingtoolbar button[disabled=false]')
```